# SQL inner join on column A and compare values in column B

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, string-matching

I am sure or maybe hope there is a simple way to do this.  Below is my latest attempt.  The query should return only one row, but I get 31.

Query:

```
    `select distinct a.[EC CERS], a.[EC Tank ID], [CIW Tank ID]
    from #tempectank a  
    inner join #tempciwtank b on a.[EC CERS] = b.[CIW CERS] 
    where a.[EC Tank ID] <> b.[CIW Tank ID]`
```

**Table Data:**

Table A

| EC CERS | EC Tank ID |
| --- | --- |
| 100338 | 1 |
| 100338 | 2 |
| 100338 | 3 |

Table B

| CIW CERS | CIW Tank ID |
| --- | --- |
| 100338 | 001 |
| 100338 | 2 |
| 100338 | 3 |

**Table Schema**

```
    create table #tempectank(
    s int IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [EC CERS] varchar(9),
    [EC Tank ID] varchar(255)
    )
```

I need the query to return one row preferably showing the EC CERS, EC Tank ID and CIW Tank ID.

Comment: Please tag you dbms.

Comment: Please include table schema and expected output

Comment: what row do you want -- what are the rules to get that row -- it is not clear what you expect from the data and description given

Comment: The table should inner join on the CERS ID.  I need the rows where the Tank ID does not match.  For example, in one case the EC Tank ID is 6 and the CIW Tank ID is WRP North.  I want this row and any other row where the Tank ID does not match returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is the matter of leading ziros , you can go with this solution:

this is not going to work if you have non-numeric in your Ids

```
Select a.[EC CERS], a.[EC Tank ID], b.[CIW Tank ID]
from #tempectank a  
inner join #tempciwtank b 
    on a.[EC CERS] = b.[CIW CERS] 
    and a.[EC Tank ID] <> b.[CIW Tank ID]
    and cast(a.[EC Tank ID] as int ) =  cast(b.[CIW Tank ID] as int)
```

actually another solution is to show the ones that you can't find a match:

```
select * from #tempectank a   
where not exists (select 1 from #tempciwtank b 
                   where a.[EC CERS] = b.[CIW CERS] 
                     and a.[EC Tank ID] = b.[CIW Tank ID]
                 )
and exists (select 1 from #tempciwtank b where a.[EC CERS] = b.[CIW CERS])
```

if you want to show non-matched cases side by side, you have to go from both side and find non-matching instances :

```
select * from (
select * from #tempectank a   
where not exists (select 1 from #tempciwtank b 
                   where a.[EC CERS] = b.[CIW CERS] 
                     and a.[EC Tank ID] = b.[CIW Tank ID]
                 )
and exists (select 1 from #tempciwtank b where a.[EC CERS] = b.[CIW CERS])
) a 
join (
select * from #tempciwtank b 
where not exists (select 1 from #tempectank a   
                   where a.[EC CERS] = b.[CIW CERS] 
                     and a.[EC Tank ID] = b.[CIW Tank ID]
                 )
and exists (select 1 from #tempectank a  where a.[EC CERS] = b.[CIW CERS])
)b 
on  a.[EC CERS] = b.[CIW CERS]
```

Comment: This query returned one row, but will it work if the field values are alphanumeric?

Comment: Just tried your query on the entire dataset and received "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '#1' to data type int."

Comment: No , it won't . but if there is a pattern in difference you can find them by another method

Comment: I don't have a consistent pattern.  I see integers, alphanumeric, and text.  For example, in one case the EC Tank ID is 6 and the CIW Tank ID is WRP North.

Comment: Wow, that is great.  Is there a way to show the CIW Tank ID?  The query returns 16 rows as is, but 49 when I try inner join #tempciwtank b on a.[EC CERS] = b.[CIW CERS]

Comment: @TryingtoCode no inner join will not five you the right result ,  if you want to show it side by side table b , you have to compare from both side  and then join, see my updated asnwer

Comment: @TryingtoCode see the third solution ,

Answer (score 0):

If you want the row where a.[EC CERS] = b.[CIW CERS] and a.[EC Tank ID] <> b.[CIW Tank ID] then try this:

```
Select a.[EC CERS], a.[EC Tank ID], b.[CIW Tank ID]
from #tempectank a  
inner join #tempciwtank b 
           on a.[EC CERS] = b.[CIW CERS] 
           and a.[EC Tank ID] <> b.[CIW Tank ID]
```

Comment: I don't think this does what OP wants. Technically it does what the verbiage says, but it probably wants the records which don't have a match, rather than a cartesian product with all differences.

Comment: I tried the Kazi  query and Error is correct.  I need just the one row.

Comment: @TryingtoCode did it helped? If not then which row you want your query to return.

Comment: May I know the reason behind downvoating?